# How to re-scale a matrix column and show the matrix in one line?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I have `p = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}};` and `q = p;`, is it possible to combine the following 2 lines into 1 line (without `;`)?

**Rescale the 3rd column and then show matrix:-**

```
q[[All, 3]] *= 5;
q
```

Or, instead, is it possible to combine the following 2 lines into 1 line?

**Copy the matrix and then rescale the 3rd column**

```
q = p;
q[[All, 3]] *= 5;
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### MapAt

```
q = MapAt[5 # &, p, {All, 3}]
```

> {{a, b, 5 c}, {d, e, 5 f}, {g, h, 5 i}}

#### ReplacePart

```
q = ReplacePart[p,  {i_, 3} :> 5 p[[i, 3]]]
```

> {{a, b, 5 c}, {d, e, 5 f}, {g, h, 5 i}}

#### ScalingMatrix + Dot

```
q = p.ScalingMatrix[{1, 1, 5}]
```

> {{a, b, 5 c}, {d, e, 5 f}, {g, h, 5 i}}

Answer (score 8):

Why not use [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) instead?

```
p . DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 5}]
```

> {{a, b, 5 c}, {d, e, 5 f}, {g, h, 5 i}}

Answer (score 5):

```
p // ScalingTransform[{1, 1, 5}]
```